# Get ModelState outside of controller and ActionFilter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, httpclientfactory

Is there a way to access the `ModelStateDictionary` from DI (outside of a Controller or ActionFilter)?  I think I can make an ActionFilter that stores a reference to the `ModelStateDictionary` somewhere, so I can access it later elsewhere, but I want to know if there's a *conventional* way to access it, like there's `IHttpContextAccessor` for `HttpContext`.

We have a web app that is a client to our api. The reason I want to do this is because I want to automatically add errors to the web app's `ModelState` from a `DelegatingHandler` used by our API client (a typed http client). The handler would watch every response from the API and, for the ones applicable (400 responses with custom error codes in the body, like "Name already taken"), add a message to the `ModelState`.

So far I've tried asking for a `ControllerContext`, but it seems to be always null.

```
var controllerContext = _serviceProvider.GetService<ControllerContext>();
controllerContext?.ModelState.AddModelError("", result.ErrorMessage);
```

I've also looked at all the registered services using the VS debugger, but I couldn't find anything promising.

---

**Side note** (quite a big one) regarding comments about SRP and separation of concerns: I don't think this violates SRP. The API client is a generic client implementation of our API, which can be consumed from anywhere (we currently use it on Xamarin and an ASP.NET Core MVC Web app - the one mentioned in this very question). However, the API client expects a `HttpClient` in its constructor, which means that its behavior can be modified by its consumers.

The Web App, for example, uses DI to provide the `HttpClient` the API client needs. That `HttpClient` is setup to use two delegating handlers, one of which is the one I've described in this question.

As to whether or not `ModelState` should be manipulated outside of controllers: well, that is exactly what libraries like `FluentValidation` (and ASP.NET default validation) does.

As to whether or not `ModelState` should be manipulated in a `DelegatingHandler`: I think this is a somewhat more valid discussion. However, no one has really presented no argument as to why this is bad.

As to wether or not this should be done "automatically": I think it's better having the code in one place than having to remember to do this every time in every action in every call to the api.

As to whether or not these messages should be even put into the `ModelState`: well, if I go into that here this *side* note would become too big. Also, no one has really argued about this, so...

Comment: why are you not using ActionFilterAttribute instead of DelegatingHandler ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot get the [`ControllerContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllercontext?view=aspnetcore-2.1) itself but what you can get is the [`ActionContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.actioncontext?view=aspnetcore-2.1) (which is a more specialized version of the controller context). You can get it by using the [`IActionContextAccessor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.infrastructure.iactioncontextaccessor?view=aspnetcore-2.1):

```
var actionContextAccessor = _serviceProvider.GetService<IActionContextAccessor>();
var actionContext = actionContextAccessor.ActionContext;
actionContext?.ModelState.AddModelError("", result.ErrorMessage);
```

You actually don’t need to resolve the action context accessor every time but can keep an instance of it around and just access the action context when you need to. The `ActionContext` will be set when you are within the scope of an action while handling a request.

An alternative solution would be to separate the concerns and store the errors somewhere else and then populate the model state from there during an action filter. That way, your solution wouldn’t be limited to a MVC way and you could also access those errors elsewhere.

Comment: That looks promising. I'll take a look after lunch. About your edit on separation of concerns: please refer to my comment on the other answer.

Comment: @andre_ss6 Although this is a solution but you should not handle model validation in such way. Do it in controller action because model validation should always belongs to controller action. Thank you.

Comment: @TanvirArjel I'm not sure if I agree. Both FluentValidation, for example, and even the default ASP.NET implementation validates the model  _and_ adds the model state errors in their middleware, before execution reaches the actual action code. 

The class that does this logic (the one that inherits from `DelegatingHandler`) is in the web app project, not the api client. Also, the handler verifies whether or not the context is null before trying to do anything, so that if the api client is used outside of an action context, nothing else happens.

Comment: @andre_ss6 Yes! You are correct! I also think so but I spoke about custom model validation and adding custom error message that what you have done should be done wither inside controller action or during the model invocation inheriting `IValidatableObject`.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you would be breaking the single responsibility principle by doing that, since the http client should not know anything about your controllers.

However, if you really want to do it, you can use lambda expressions to pass a reference of the ModelStateDictionary to your delegate, please see: [Passing delegate function with extra parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14324803/passing-delegate-function-with-extra-parameters)

If you don't want to break the SRP, one option would be to make the http client return a list of errors to be added by the controller to the modelstate (or null if no errors)

Comment: Yea, I don't think I'm violating the SRP. The api client is a library of its own. However, since it uses the new "typed http client" convention brought by `IHttpClientFactory` (which is just `HttpClient` DI with some extension methods to help), there are extension points which you can use to alter the api client behavior. Wrapping it up: the client is its own library, with only general api client logic. The delegating handler, however, is in the web app project, and extends the client's functionality.