# Generic Delegate with dll ref/out function as Input (solved) and log it

Tags: c#, .net-5, c#-9.0

**What i got**

So basically I am all over the a generic solution for a dll wrapper function to achieve logging/errorhandling easily. All my dll functions return a `bool`. dll is in c++

after looking at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24044772/175679) and that [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14324803/passing-delegate-function-with-extra-parameters) to name just a few i got to the point, that i basically do not care for the passed parameters of my dll function and all calls basically work like this:

```
ExecuteCommand(() => DllInterface.DllFunction([someParams]));
```

with

```
private static void ExecuteCommand(Func<bool> aCommand, string logmessage = null, bool DoThrow = true)
    {
        if (!aCommand()) 
        {
          if (DoThrow) 
          {
            throw new Exception(DllInterface.LastError()); 
          }
          else 
          {
            Log.Error(aCommand.Method.Name);
          }
        }           
        else 
        {
          Log.Information(aCommand.Method.Name);
        }
    }
```

with that i should be able to call any function regardless of its signature.

problem is, I sometimes want to receive informations from the dll as well and therefore use ref or out.

since `Func<bool>` doesnt like ref i tried to do something like this:

```
 public delegate V RefFunc<in T, U , out V>(T input, out U refType);
```

according to link one. this works fine as long `T` and `V` are nice types, but i couldn't found a solution, to write a lambda if `T`is a `Func<bool>`. Test usage was implented in this way;

```
RefFunc<double, int, bool> refFunc = (double adouble, out int testint) =>
         {
             testint = (int)Math.Truncate(adouble);
             return true;
         };
Reffunc(adouble, out int aInt);
```

**what i wanted (and already got)**

is basically a overload of Execute command which accepts
ExecuteCommand(() = > DllInterface.DllFunctions(ref int rval));
and actually executes
...if(!acCommand(ref rval) ...
is this possible?

**Answer**
The Answer was already there, as it turns out I can pass any functions to the current `ExecuteCommand()`, since the signature passed as a command is defined by the Lambda, not the function the Lambda is calling.

Comment: I don't see that you need another overload. `Execute` does the same thing either way. The lambdas are created in the calling code, and can close over any `ref` parameter you want, so long as they return a `bool`. Aside `in/out` on generic parameters mean something completely different (variance) than on the actual argument definition (marshalling).

Comment: Actually on the way home from work yesterday i had the assumption that i overcomplicated it way too much and never actually ever tried to use ref with execute. turns out it did
Asu you may noticed im fairly new to using delagates and the concept of manipulating variance

Comment: Not really possible without using reflection. But I don't know why you would want to do that anyway. And if you have a different question, you should post an answer to the original one here, then create a new question.

Comment: well basically the answer is what you said, there is no problem in the first place, i should proberbly delete the question?

Comment: You could but don't have to. You can answer your own question if you want. But you shouldn't put two questions in one. If you have a different question post that separately

Comment: got it, thanks for the advise